# Controller is not returning Viewbag value to the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller named CallAllocation, and a View CallAllocation.
At first when the page loads **only** two dropdown appears with a submit button. On submission, page gets filled with rest of the details based on the selection from the two dropdowns. To achieve that I have made the following code:

*Please focus on ViewBag.IsValid condition*

**My Controller be like**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CallAllocation()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        try
        {
            var NatureList = (from a in dataContext.CallNatures
                              select a);

            Allocation Allocate = new Allocation();

            Allocate.CallNaturelist = NatureList.ToList();

            ViewData["SelectedTicket"] = 0;

            Allocate.CallTicketList = null;

            ViewBag.IsValid = "";

            return View(Allocate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["ErrMsg"] = ex.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("ShowError");
        }
    }
```

**My View be like**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("CallAllocation", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmCallAllocate"}))
                            {    
                                 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                 @Html.ValidationSummary()
                                 @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrMsg)

                                <div class="row ">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        @if (ViewBag.IsVaild == "True")
                                        {
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCallNature, new SelectList(Model.CallNaturelist, "CallNatureID", "Description"),
                                                            "Select Nature", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "dropdown1", @readonly = "readonly;" })   

                                            @Html.DropDownList("CallTicket", new SelectList(string.Empty, "CallTicketNumber", "CallTicketNumber"), "Select Call Ticket",
                                                        new { style = "width:250px", @class = "dropdown1" , @readonly = "readonly;" })   


                                                    <input type="submit" value="Get Ticket" style="background-color:#C5C5C5"/> 

                                        }
                                        else 
                                        {

                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCallNature, new SelectList(Model.CallNaturelist, "CallNatureID", "Description"),
                                                            "Select Nature", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "dropdown1" })   

                                         @Html.DropDownList("CallTicket", new SelectList(string.Empty, "CallTicketNumber", "CallTicketNumber"), "Select Call Ticket",
                                                        new { style = "width:250px", @class = "dropdown1"})   


                                                    <input type="submit" value="Get Ticket" style="background-color:#C5C5C5"/> 
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
```

As you can see Controller sends ViewBag value "", and it should enter **else** condition of the View. But it is bypassing both the conditions. 
Please help me understand why the controller is unable to send Viewbag value to the view. I have made similar cases but it's working in rest.
I have tried clearing the cache too.
Please note that my View is a strongly-typed View.

Comment: What you you mean its _bypassing both the conditions_? And `IsValid` (controller) is not the same as `IsVaild` (view)

Comment: Bypassing means it is not entering the  else  condition. What do you mean by IsValid (controller) is not the same as IsVaild (view)?

Comment: Look at them carefully! (different spelling)

Comment: And what makes you think that its not entering the `else` block? - and the code is identical (except for a pointless and invalid `readonly` attribute - there is no such thing as a readonly `<select>`) so why do you even have an `if/else` block

Comment: Thanks Stephen that was a silly typing mistake.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I disable dropdown selection on clicking Submit button? There I will set Viewbag.IsValid as True in the [HttpPost] part of the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137741/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sameep-baxi).